# How can I stop the Nikon D90 from bracketing?

Tags: nikon-d90, camera-controls, bracketing

How can I stop the Nikon D90 from bracketing?  It does not have an off option.  I have followed the manual's directions, but it's still playing up, particularly with flash and TTL mode.

Answer (score 4):

Hold down the BKT button (front left beside lens) and rotate the rear thumbwheel until it says 0F (zero frames) in the top display.  I don't think there is equivalent way to shut it off via the menus.

By the way, the front thumbwheel controls the f/stop difference between each exposure.

If you only ever want to do exposure bracketing, you can go to custom menu e4 and switch the setting from "AE and Flash" to "AE only".  But as far as I know, the only way to turn it off completely is by setting the top display to 0F.

Edit: dug out my manual, it's at the top of page 193 in a section "*Cancelling Bracketing*"